# What are the risks involved with linking Voter Card with Aadhaar for Indians?

Tags: india, voter-registration, identity-document

With the passing of **[THE ELECTION LAWS (AMENDMENT) BILL, 2021](https://prsindia.org/files/bills_acts/bills_parliament/2021/The%20Election%20Laws%20(Amendment)%20Bill,%202021.pdf)** in Rajya Sabha on Dec 21, 2021, the new sub-sections were added in *section 23* of the **[Representation of the People Act, 1950](https://legislative.gov.in/sites/default/files/A1950-43.pdf)**, according to which the *electoral registration officer*, may ask the applicant to furnish the Aadhaar card <sup>**1**</sup> to establish his/her identity.

Ever since the bill was passed the [members of the parliament belonging to the opposition are protesting against it](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/linking-electoral-roll-to-aadhaar-opposition-objects-govt-pushes-bill-through-7682680/), but **what are the exact ways in which this linking can be misused by the government or the members of the political party sitting in power?**

---

<sup>**1**</sup> An identification card having a unique 12-digit number issued by the Unique Identification Authority of India (UIDAI). Named after the Aadhaar Act. *See,* [Aadhaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aadhaar).

Comment: Whenever there is a *may* in such a regulation, there is the risk of uneven enforcement: Registration officers might always require the card in districts that tend to vote for the opposition, and never in districts that vote for the government. This could discourage opposition supporters.

Comment: What is an Aadhaar card?

Comment: What is the public acceptance of the card? Are there people complaining about the risks for their privacy? Are there people worried about possible misuse by the authorities? AFAIK the government already used several tricks to render the card mandatory, this might be another one.

Comment: @ohwill - Adhar means support , It's similar like social security no.  In United States. This social security number is mandatory and is must for receiving gov.  benefits like various subsidies or simply to open bank account or to buy a mobile sim. It's a most essential thing in the must have for a Indian national.Without which there is no way , one can't do anything.

Comment: The Aadhaar card seems to require providing biometric data as well as the number.  Would that be required to prove identity to an election official?  It's also not clear whether the officials may require the card or if the person has to elect to link the card, but even in the latter case it could create a disparate impact if proving identity with the card is significantly faster than proving identity without it.

Comment: The parallel issue in the U.S. is that a significant number of low income and older people don't have government issued ID but are registered to vote. I wonder if the same issue is at work here.

Answer (score -1):

It is risky for those, who are not residing in an area where they registered for voting. Afterwards, both are linked major of illegal & fake voters will be removed from each area of India. One non-resident who earns by doing fake votings will be unemployed or useless. Once it's done then only real residents who are living in their area will be only able to fix their area further, outsiders’ voting or views will be closed for residents further.